# If there is a duplicate value in the arraylist how to remove the duplicate and the first item which caused the duplication in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, arraylist

I have an arraylist with few items in it.

ex: `id = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

When a duplicate comes from the for loop as the next element I want to remove that duplicate and the item already in the arraylist
ex: `new id = 3`

Expected result: `id = [1 ,2 ,4 , 5]`

Here's how the code looks like

```js
var SampleArray = [1,  2, 3, 4, 5] ;
export default class MainActivity extends Component {
 
  constructor(props) {
       super(props)
       this.state = {
         Holder: ''
       }
     }
 
  AddItemsToArray=()=>{
     SampleArray.push( this.state.Holder.toString());
        console.log(SampleArray.toString())
        var sorted_arr = SampleArray.slice().sort();
        var results = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < sorted_arr.length - 1; i++) {
            if (sorted_arr[i + 1] != sorted_arr[i]) {
                results.push(sorted_arr[i]);
            }
        }
        console.log(results.toString());
  }
 
 render() {
   return (
      <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
          <TextInput
              placeholder="Enter Value here"
              onChangeText={TextInputValue => this.setState({ Holder : TextInputValue }) }
                  style={{textAlign: 'center', marginBottom: 6, height: 45}}
            />
           <Button title="Click Here To Add Value To Array" onPress={this.AddItemsToArray} />
          </View>
 
   );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `indexOf` and `splice` method

```
id = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
newId = 3;
index = id.indexOf(newId);
index !== -1 && id.splice(index, 1);
console.log(id) // [1,2,4,5]
```

Comment: The nextId comes from a for loop. So I have to figure out how can I get it out of the for loop.

Comment: @Charitha.R pass it to a function? E.g., `for (/* loop condition */) { callFunction(i) }` or pass more stuff if appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

First use `indexOf` to find index of the `newId` in `id`.

```
var index = id.indexOf(newId)
```

Then check for valid valid index, if it returns a valid index then use `splice` and `break` out of the for loop,

```
if(index !== -1) {
    id = id.splice(index,1);
    break;
}
```